# Efficient iteration through input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got something like this in input:

1 2 121 212 3131 12 ....

So it is: 
number space number space number ...

There can be up to 10^7 numbers with range [0-10^9]
What I've got now:

```
inputTab = input().split()
for num, i in inputTab:
    // do things
```

I am looking for fast way to iterate through all numbers and thier indexes ( do some things inside loop)

Thank you

Comment: `input()` `return`s a string in Python 3; but anyway this is too broad. You can use a `for` loop, comprehension, or other things depending on what you're actually trying to do. If you want the indexes start with `for i,num in enumerate(map(int,inputTab)):`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `enumerate` and `map` in python3 both are iterator objects (lazily evaluated). Its quick enough.

```
for num, i in enumerate(map(int, inputTab)):
    // do things
```

Comment: Why is it quick enough? Quick enough for what? Also, it looks like you have have copied my comment (at least in part)

Comment: @Chris_Rands, first check the timestamps, i was writting the answer while you was writting the comment, chill man :( its not too much more that can be done with the info, it is so weird to have the same idea?

Comment: Apologies if you didn't copy, just noticed you edited in the `map(int())` well after my comment, but perhaps coincidence :) Anyway, I still don't know why your claiming this is quick enough